# Conditional IF statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following tables:

**Model** Table

```
Model    State  FH

NEW-20  1   279

NEW-20  2   279

NEW-20  3   204

NEW-20  4   186

NEW-21  1   333
```

**SA** Table

```
Driver  Year    Scenario;

GDP 2013    Nominal

Fuel    2013    Nominal

Mili    2013    Nominal

GDP 2014    Nominal

Fuel    2014    Nominal

Mili    2014    Nominal

GDP 2015    Nominal

Fuel    2015    Nominal
```

**UTI** Table

```
Driver  Scenario    State        var1       var2      var3       var4      var5      var6;

GDP Nominal  1             0.0% 0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%

GDP Strong_G     2             10.0%    12.0%   7.5%    10.0%   10.0%   0.0%

GDP Mild_D       4                  -5.0%        -8.0%  -4.0%   -10.0%  -8.0%   -2.5%

Mil Strong_D     1            -6.0% -10.0%  -6.0%   -12.0%  -10.0%  -5.0%

MIL Nominal  1             0.0% 0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%
```

I'd like to use a conditional IF statement. What is the correct syntax? Here's an idea of what I'd like to do:

```
(IF Model.State & SA.Driver (GDP) & SA.Scenario = UTI.Driver & UTI.Scenario & UTI.State
THEN  SUMPRODUCT((1+(UTI.VAR1--VAR6));MODEL.FH)  

+

IF Model.State & SA.Driver(Fuel) & SA.Scenario = UTI.Driver & UTI.Scenario & UTI.State
THEN  SUMPRODUCT((1+(UTI.VAR1--VAR6));MODEL.FH)

+

IF Model.State & SA.Driver(Mil) & SA.Scenario = UTI.Driver & UTI.Scenario & UTI.State
THEN SUMPRODUCT((1+(UTI.VAR1--VAR6));MODEL.FH)) 

AS TOTAL
```

How can I do it in SAS?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use `PROC SQL`?

If so, then you are looking for the `CASE` statement:

```
(CASE WHEN Model.State & SA.Driver (GDP) & SA.Scenario = UTI.Driver & UTI.Scenario & UTI.State
THEN  SUMPRODUCT((1+(UTI.VAR1--VAR6));MODEL.FH) ELSE 0 /* <- Insert else case here */ END

+

CASE WHEN Model.State & SA.Driver(Fuel) & SA.Scenario = UTI.Driver & UTI.Scenario & UTI.State
THEN  SUMPRODUCT((1+(UTI.VAR1--VAR6));MODEL.FH) ELSE 0 /* <- Insert else case here */


+

CASE WHEN Model.State & SA.Driver(Mil) & SA.Scenario = UTI.Driver & UTI.Scenario & UTI.State
THEN SUMPRODUCT((1+(UTI.VAR1--VAR6));MODEL.FH) ELSE 0 /* <- Insert else case here */ END)

AS TOTAL
```

*I don't recognize chunks of your code. Either you are using some sort of pseduo-code or you are using advanced SAS techniques I've never seen before. Take the above with a grain of salt.*